# Editing Image size in boundless theme product page?

Tags: shopify

I can cut the visual image in half but cant seem to find out how to reduce the product images as a whole. Anyone figure this out?

Comment: can you tell us more about what you want to do exactly ?

Comment: On  the boundless theme on the shopify website store. On the product pages the images shown are massive. I tried to edit the cut and best i can do is cut them down from size by like 25% not sure how to reduce the size of the images on the product page. I have alot of variants per product

Comment: You try with the theme editor or with custom coding ?

Comment: Best i could find was to change code from one half to one third and it reduced size that was it. I cant find where the image resolution is set at in the files. For some reason this layout is more complicated to do that than the others. I also dont know coding too  well tbh